# Declaring methods of parent and child classes to ensure they run together

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm currently struggling with the development of a todo list (mostly unimportant) within which I am creating a base class "Task", which has the classes "Note", "extendedTask" and "Reminder". I also have a class called "Appointment" that inherits from reminder.

All of these classes implement an interface with a method called "detailsShow" I want the method to be called from the child classes and then call the same method from the parent class.

The method in the base class is defined as such

```
public virtual string detailsShow()
    {
        return "Description: " + _taskDescription;
    }
```

While the child class defines it in this way (Note is used in this example as it has the least number of variables)

```
public override string detailsShow()
    {
        return "Details: " + _noteDescription;
    }
```

I suspect it is how i have defined both the method in the base class and the method in the child classes.

On another note, how do i begin a new line in a RichText box

(How i want it to look)

```
Stuffhere
Andstuffhere
```

(what i get using my method)

```
Stuffhere \nAndstuffhere
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see what is your question...?

Comment: You may have more luck asking the second question in another post. Or, look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7069784/117625

Comment: Mutually subscribed multicast delegate comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the current structure of your code, your inheritor can call it's parent, as in:

```
public override string detailsShow()
{
    return base.detailsShow() + " Details: " + _noteDescription;
}
```

which could yield something like:

```
Description: Stuffhere Details: Andstuffhere
```

You cannot have a reference to the base class `Task` and force it to execute the `virtual detailsShow` as the inheritor gets to make that decision.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the detailsShow method of the base class and include Environment.NewLine to begin a new line in the RichTextBox:

```
public override string detailsShow()
{
    return base.detailsShow() + Environment.NewLine + 
        "Details: " + _noteDescription;
}
```