# String built from multiple Richtextboxes looses formatting

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

i have built a form for creating a ticket.
The Message-text was in one Richtextbox at first.
The LongText is being sent in a webrequest as String.
Since i build the longtext from three Richtextboxes the formatting of the line-breaks (and only the line-breaks) is broken.

Now i have changed it to three boxes:
- the first one with a greeting-phrase
- the main one with your long text 
- the last one with a "Best Regards" phrase

The Form looks like this:

[image: Form-sample]

**The problem:** 
creating the string that i want to pass over malforms my final string and i don't know why.

I build my final string like this:

```
     Dim MyFinstr as string = RTB1.text & vbnewline &
 vbnewline & RTB2.text & vbnewline & vbnewline & RTB3.text
```

My final string *should* look like this:

```
Hello mr Test,

long text 1
longtext line2 
long ipsum

Best Regards 
Mr Blaze
```

Instead it always looks like this:

```
Hello mr Test,
long text 1
longtext line2 
long ipsum
Best Regards 
Mr Blaze
```

So - somehow - when the string is built out of the texts of the 3 Richtexboxes it breaks.

Now comes the most confusing part: 
If i do not assign the content from the richtextboxes to a string and do *this*

```
  AnoterRichtextbox.text = RTB1.text & vbnewline &
 vbnewline & RTB2.text & vbnewline & vbnewline & RTB3.text 
Dim MyFinstr as String = AnoterRichtextbox.text
```

Then the string is fine and has the line-breaks in the end.

My *dirty workaround* is an invisible fourth richtextbox that kinda converts my String to look fine. But i really do not understand why that is so.

The strings look the same if i copy it to clipboard and view it in Notepad++ with the line-breaks. But - in the end - the ticket generated by the webrequest has broken formatting with the string that is not converted from the Richtextbox4.

Do you have a hint on what i am overseeing ? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I could not reproduce this behavior. Any luck using the `Lines` property like `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, RTB1.Lines)`? Do you really need to use a RTB control? Please note that the line endings in a RTB control is `LF` not `CRLF`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082742

Comment: I can only reproduce it by looking at the result of the webrequest as well, that is a bit odd. In Notepad++ it showed crlf as line-break. I will test it tomorrow and report back :)

Comment: Since you're not using any actual RichText here, why not use a standard MultiLine TextBox?

Comment: I have replaced the vbnewline with vblf, that has not changed the issue.      Edit: a mutliline-textbox is producing the same results.

Answer (score 1):

may you should look about `ControlChars`
like this:

```
 RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(ControlChars.Lf, ControlChars.CRLF)
```

Comment: I have done this conversion with the string "MyFinstr" . The String is built by joining the Richtextbox-texts and putting the line-breaks inbetween.  
However it does not change the formatting - problem.

Comment: try to manually ad a `&"\r\n"&`, instead of `vbnewline`, may this will work...

my virtualbasic is a bit rusty^^

may vbnewline is checking the last line, only if there are any chars, then it will do a newline... print a spacechar `&" "&` at the empty line will possibly work